# How do site analytics tools know the URL that visitors were referred from?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics, analytics

I'm building a rudimentary tracking tool for one of my sites, and I'm realizing that Google Analytics and my Squarespace site are aware of the URL that referred my visitors to my site.

For example, Squarespace's analytics can detect the exact URL of the pinterest pin that 3 of my visitors came from, which blog post referred 15 visitors to me, etc. How can my server possibly know who referred them to my site?

I'm a full stack .Net/C#/Javascript engineer and have no ideas. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer  is one way, they may have more sophisticated methods also though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [HTTP referrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header that is usually populated by default by your browser upon clicking links. It's possible to disable this as the browser is what chooses to include the header. You can make requests in a variety of other ways and leave that header blank, but clicking a simple link in a standard browser is pretty much always going to include the header.

[image]
[(click for larger view)](https://i.imgur.com/DW7wU3Y.gif)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't know about that. That video was super helpful btw. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @Chev what did you use to create that gif?

Comment: @mikey I used [Camtasia for Mac](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia-features.html) :)

Comment: @iAmWonder Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

basically, when you click a link on a site, that site will send location(the URL) information to the destination page, which your server logs.